# Why does MaxId function always return 9 in xml?

Tags: c#

I use `MaxId` function to return max id in my xml file, but it always returns 9 and I can not insert new record with correct id.

xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestTag>
    <Test Id="1" devicename="desk"  date="2012-02-01T00:00:00" username="z" />
    <Test Id="2" devicename="c"     date="2012-02-01T00:00:00" username="z"/>
    .
    .
    . 
    <Test Id="12" devicename="q"  date="2012-02-01T00:00:00" username="z"/>
    <Test Id="13" devicename="m"  date="2012-02-01T00:00:00" username="z"/>
</TestTag>
```

I use this MaxId function:

```cs
public string MaxId()
{
    string maxNr = xd.XPathSelectElements("//TestTag/Test")
            .Max(c => (string)c.Attribute("Id"));
    return maxNr;  // it is always 9
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 .Max(c => (string)c.Attribute("Id"))
```

will select the geatest *string*. And "9" > "77"

So either make your attributes sortable ("0009" < "0077") or convert them to int:

```
 .Max(c => int.parse(c.Attribute("Id").Value))
```